# Where Binary Search Tree data-structure used

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am new to data-structures in javascript and was trying to understand like how to figure out that if particular problem should be solved using BST. What kind of problems should we approach to solve using BST.

Comment: This is a bit broad for StackOverflow.  But just reading and following the links from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) should give you plenty of information.

Comment: @Scott Sauyet Thats a good suggestion, but I thought of asking it here so to get a right direction, also some good examples from the experts :-)

Comment: Tbh, I have rarely seen BST being used so much in context other than learning data structures. That is because there exist other BST structures which are also balanced (Red Black Tree, AVL tree ....) which offer better guarantees on the performance than BSTs. For instance, `C++`'s `std::map` is implemented using red-black trees, some maps in java as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it used in many search applications where data is constantly entering/leaving, such as the map and set objects in many languages libraries. And it support insert and delete operation and it keeps data in sorted order and it is base of data structures like Red-Black trees and AVL trees

For example you want to find the largest number in Binary search tree, you start from root node and you always search right subtrees until you reach the leaf node.
The Time Complexity of search operation on a BST is O(log N) on average that means if you increase your number of data from 10 to 1 million, your wait time just increases from 4 to 20 so it is very time efficient Compared with linear search and try all possible ways one by one. Thanks to m.raynal i forgot to say time complexity of the operation in the worst case in O(N)

You can find and solve some problems about Binary Search algorithm and BST Data structure to understand better in [CodeForces](https://codeforces.com/problemset?order=BY_RATING_ASC&tags=binary%20search)

Comment: "The Time Complexity of search operation on a BST is O(log N)" -> This is the average case, not the worst one. In the worst case (BST built from a sorted array), the complexity of operations is `O(n)`